# Como tratar payloads dinâmicos no Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, design-pattern

Olá, gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor forma de modelar o recebimento de payloads com dados dinamicos, ou seja, as vezes posso receber uma requisição com 3 campos, outras, com 5, etc.

Por exemplo, num mesmo endpoint eu posso receber requisições como:

```
{
  "nome": "Juninho",
  "dataNascimento": "26/01/2000"
}
```

Ou

```
{
  "nome": "Maria",
  "sobrenome": "Joaquina",
  "dataNascimento": "23/12/1999"
}
```

Tentei receber no meu controller e jogar para um Strategy e esse strategy modelar meu dado e validar a informação de acordo com algum identificador padrão de envio que o cliente informar.

Exemplo 1 :  Identificador A,Nome,Data de Nascimento
Exemplo 2 : Nome, Sobrenome, Data de nascimento , Altura.

Assim, eu pegaria esse identificador e saberia qual modelo adotar para salvar no meu banco de dados de forma certa, validar as informações corretamente no meu validators e inserir no meu documento com os campos corretos e não nulos.

Porém, não sei se essa é a melhor forma ou se existe uma outra forma. Não sei se o strategy se aplica nesse contexto, pensei também no Abstract factory mas acredito que não se aplique.

Existe uma outra forma mais simples?

Já consigo salvar o recebimento qualquer que seja dentro de um modelo generico, no qual tem todos os campos e tipos, porém acredito não ser a melhor pratica pois caso um determinado tipo de payload não preencha alguns campos, esses campos ficam com valores nulos e a validação mais complexa, além de a cada adição de um comportamento novo, precisar adicionar mais campos nesse modelo generico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o mais simples seja ter uma interface comum para os N modelos que você tiver, e aí você usa uma `Factory` para converter o dado que tu recebeu para esta interface.

```js
interface Monstro {
  validar(): boolean;
}

class Bruxa implements Monstro {
  constructor(
    public nivelFeiura: number,
    public poder: number,
    public tipoVassoura: string
  ) {}

  validar() {
    const FEIURA_MINIMA = 665;

    return (
      this.nivelFeiura > FEIURA_MINIMA &&
      this.tipoVassoura !== 'Vassoura Normal'
    );
  }
}

class Goblin implements Monstro {
  constructor(public arma: string, public alturaEmCm: number) {}

  validar() {
    return this.armaValida() && this.alturaValida();
  }

  private armaValida() {
    const armasValidas = [
      'Faca',
      'Adaga',
      'Peixeira',
      'Canivete',
      'Caco de Vidro',
    ];
    return armasValidas.includes(this.arma);
  }

  private alturaValida() {
    return this.alturaEmCm >= 70 && this.alturaEmCm <= 120;
  }
}

class MonstroFactory {
  criarMonstro(payload: Record<string, string | number>): Monstro {
    if ('nivelFeiura' in payload) {
      return new Bruxa(
        Number(payload.nivelFeiura),
        Number(payload.poder),
        String(payload.tipoVassoura)
      );
    }

    if ('arma' in payload) {
      return new Goblin(String(payload.arma), Number(payload.alturaEmCm));
    }

    throw new Error('Monstro desconhecido');
  }
}
```

Com isso, você pode olhar para o seu payload em um nível mais alto de abstração, seguindo o princípio de substituição de Liskov. Seja Goblin ou Bruxa, você sabe que é um monstro e que dá pra validar ele. Naturalmente, será simples adicionar outros monstros depois.

Agora, assim, antes de sair aplicando design pattern e tudo o mais, é preciso ter algum critério. Será que seu problema realmente pede por esse tipo de solução, ou se trata de algo simples, em que apenas difere um ou dois campos?  Na dúvida, mantenha o mais simples e direto possível, caso contrário poderá estar trazendo complexidade desnecessária para seu código.

Comment: Também vale a pena ponderar se esse envio de vários modelos diferentes em um mesmo endpoint não fere o SRP. Isto é, se não faria sentido ter diferentes endpoints para cada modelo. Depende muito do que você está implementando.

Comment: Perfeito Allan, no meu caso e uma mesma funcionalidade que dependendo do combobox selecionado ganha novos campos ou outras nomeclaturas. Com isso preciso receber essa informação de forma dinamica e modela/validar ela para salvar no meu banco de forma diferente pois os campos podem ter tipos diferentes ou tamanhos.
Agora o factory faz mais sentido com seu exemplo do que usar o strategy.
A principio estava salvando tudo da mesma forma, numa interface grande que não diferenciava o recebimento das informaçoes, com todos os campos possiveis. Agora estou tentando modelar esse recebimento.